Error: This template attempted to load an untrusted component 'IntegrationWizard'
Error this template attempted to load an untrusted component IntegrationWizard,
Version 1.0.0.1,
Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=0c4054c4c0e4dca0,
For more information on this problem and how to enable this template, please documentation on Customizing Project Templates(don't have )
this is what gets displayed when i create a new project using the CSharpIntegration template i need to use this template but when ever i click and press ok it gives this error
If possible help me and thanks :
enter image description here
enter image description here
